# Google map v2 api not tracking user location

Tags: android, google-api

For some reason my `MapFragment` won't show the user location anymore? Map tiles are still displayed but it's not displaying current location??

```
         public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

                protected void onPreExecute() {

                    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                            .getMap();
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place, 4000));
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
                    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                    map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
                    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


            }
```

This is my basic `MapFragment` which normally worked until i started testing on another Android device which uses the same android version only difference is theres no SIM card in the device. Does that make a difference??

Manifest-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


        <application 
            android:icon="@drawable/applogo12" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">


        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>




        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="-----" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have no idea how the api has stopped working.
Any feedback appreciated

Comment: Based on the code supplied I'm surprised it ever showed the user location. Where is youre `LocationListener`? Where/how are you displaying the `Marker` for the user? Just getting a `LocationManager` is not going to do anything.

Comment: Try FakeGPS location https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps If it works then then problem is that there is no GPS indoors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sim card absence could be an issue. I have the same trouble wasn't able to get location without sim card (no SIM - no network location provider), because GPS location provider couldn't determine location indoors.